# Flutter Camera Plugin Recorded Video Quality

Tags: flutter, dart

I record video with flutter camera package. However recorded video quality is very low although I set resolutionPreset is `ResolutionPreset.max`. Video details: video's resolution 640/480 which I record from flutter, video's resolution 1920/1080 whick I record with device native camera application. How can I improve video quality like as video recorded by native camera application?

Comment: Did you initialize the controller like this? `controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);`

Comment: Yes I have already initialized with ResolutionPreset.max but it is not determine maximum supported resolution preset mentioned in documentation. I have some search on repo and it looks like bug :/